# How to handle numbers in column names in Snowflake

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am converting SQL Server tables to snowflake and some column names have numbers in them which are accepted in SQL Server but not snowflake. It's important that they retain the same name. Does anyone have any info on how to get around this syntax issue?

```
--- ms sql server syntax ---
CREATE TABLE naviguard.dbo.NPR_PROC_CD_MODS_IMPACT (
    proc_cd varchar(7) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    PROC_SRV_TYP_CD varchar(3) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    clm_cnt bigint NULL,
    [0_mods_clm_cnt] bigint NULL, --- columns with numbers
    [0_mods_clm_pct] decimal(5,4) NULL,
    [1_mods_clm_cnt] bigint NULL,
    [1_mods_clm_pct] decimal(5,4) NULL,
    [2_mods_clm_cnt] bigint NULL,
    [2_mods_clm_pct] decimal(5,4) NULL,
    [3_mods_clm_cnt] bigint NULL,
    [3_mods_clm_pct] decimal(5,4) NULL,
    [4_mods_clm_cnt] bigint NULL,
    [4_mods_clm_pct] decimal(5,4) NULL,
    mods_var_mode1 varchar(12) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    mods_var_mode1_clm_cnt bigint NULL,
    mods_var_mode2 varchar(12) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    mods_var_mode2_clm_cnt bigint NULL,
    mods_var_mode3 varchar(12) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    mods_var_mode3_clm_cnt bigint NULL,
    mods_var_3_mode_cnt bigint NULL,
    mods_var_3_mode_pct decimal(5,4) NULL,
    any_mods_clm_cnt bigint NULL,
    any_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4) NULL,
    impact_mods_clm_cnt bigint NULL,
    impact_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK__NPR_PROC__A2159902E557C34D PRIMARY KEY (proc_cd)
);

--- snowflake syntax ---
CREATE TABLE naviguard.dbo.NPR_PROC_CD_MODS_IMPACT (
    proc_cd varchar(7)  NOT NULL,
    PROC_SRV_TYP_CD varchar(3) ,
    clm_cnt bigint,
    0_mods_clm_cnt bigint, --- unaccepted number columns
    0_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4),
    1_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
    1_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4),
    2_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
    2_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4),
    3_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
    3_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4),
    4_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
    4_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4),
    mods_var_mode1 varchar(12) ,
    mods_var_mode1_clm_cnt bigint,
    mods_var_mode2 varchar(12) ,
    mods_var_mode2_clm_cnt bigint,
    mods_var_mode3 varchar(12) ,
    mods_var_mode3_clm_cnt bigint,
    mods_var_3_mode_cnt bigint,
    mods_var_3_mode_pct decimal(5,4),
    any_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
    any_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4),
    impact_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
    impact_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4)
);
```

Error Message:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 1 unexpected '0'.

Comment: Does it help if you enclose them inside double quotes?

Comment: Did you check [Snowflake's documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html)?

Comment: "If an identifier is not enclosed in double quotes, it must begin with a letter or underscore (_) and cannot contain extended characters or blank spaces."

Comment: Hi, you have couple of options, 
1)  you could use double quote around the column name 
2) You can remove the numbers 
3) Replace the numbers with the word one_ or two_ . 
4) Move the number at the last in eg  0_mods_clm_cnt  becomes mods_clm_cnt_0. 

I think the best options looks like number 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments where right. Adding double quotes to the columns containing numbers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Simplified original, with a syntax error:

```sql
CREATE TABLE naviguard.dbo.NPR_PROC_CD_MODS_IMPACT (
    clm_cnt bigint,
    0_mods_clm_cnt bigint, --- unaccepted number columns
    0_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4)
```

Fixed with quotes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE naviguard.dbo.NPR_PROC_CD_MODS_IMPACT (
    clm_cnt bigint,
    "0_mods_clm_cnt" bigint, --- unaccepted number columns
    "0_mods_clm_pct" decimal(5,4)
)
```

Note that now you'll always need to add quotes and type in lower caps when referring to these columns:

```sql
select clm_cnt, "0_mods_clm_cnt"
from NPR_PROC_CD_MODS_IMPACT
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE or replace TABLE NPR_PROC_CD_MODS_IMPACT (
proc_cd varchar(7)  NOT NULL,
PROC_SRV_TYP_CD varchar(3) ,
clm_cnt bigint,
"0_mods_clm_cnt" bigint, --- unaccepted number columns
"0_mods_clm_pct" decimal(5,4),
"1_mods_clm_cnt" bigint,
"1_mods_clm_pct" decimal(5,4),
"2_mods_clm_cnt" bigint,
"2_mods_clm_pct" decimal(5,4),
"3_mods_clm_cnt" bigint,
"3_mods_clm_pct" decimal(5,4),
"4_mods_clm_cnt" bigint,
"4_mods_clm_pct" decimal(5,4),
mods_var_mode1 varchar(12) ,
mods_var_mode1_clm_cnt bigint,
mods_var_mode2 varchar(12) ,
mods_var_mode2_clm_cnt bigint,
mods_var_mode3 varchar(12) ,
mods_var_mode3_clm_cnt bigint,
mods_var_3_mode_cnt bigint,
mods_var_3_mode_pct decimal(5,4),
any_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
any_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4),
impact_mods_clm_cnt bigint,
impact_mods_clm_pct decimal(5,4)
);

select "0_mods_clm_pct" from NPR_PROC_CD_MODS_IMPACT

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).